# Getting sound pressure level (SPL) for a frequency band from Welch's derived PSD

Tags: sound, octave, power-spectral-density

I'm using Welch's method (pwelch, in octave) to get the PSD of a recorded sound signal (i.e. pressure level vs. time). I then took the PSD data and took the sum of the amplitude in each octave band (1/3 octave). My question is: how can I convert the PSD data to a sound pressure level (per band, or per frequency if I do it before 1/3 octave sort/sum). For an overall SPL, I can take the pre-PSD estimation data and calculate via the equation Lp = 20 log10(Prms/Pref).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to factor in you'er transduce characteristics to do anything meaningful with PSD numbers.

Comment: In what way? The PSD values are derived from the scaled transducer output, i.e have already been converted from voltage to pressure.

Comment: Just want to make sure you have your calibration right.  You should check your results at various levels and frequency bands with a calibrated SPL meter to make sure.  Someone posted this https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl&fromgroups#!msg/comp.soft-sys.matlab/6Kr2SbZ6lmM/UX_qsn0yIiIJ which may be helpful.